# SQL find SUM of MAX values

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and struggling with this query, any help much appreciated.

My table looks like this:

| id | score | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 250 | 1 |
| 2 | 350 | 1 |
| 2 | 850 | 2 |
| 2 | 260 | 2 |
| 2 | 750 | 3 |
| 2 | 560 | 3 |

I'd like to calculate a total score as the max score from each level.

So in layman's: Total Score = Max score from level 1 + Max score from level 2 + Max score from level 3

How do I replicate that in SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please tag with database platform

Comment: GROUP BY, then SUM its result.

Comment: I think  you use sub-queries like `SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(table.score) WHERE level = N) AS 'level_1_score'....`.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `SUM` on the result of a sub-query:

```
SELECT
   SUM(max_score) AS total_score 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         MAX(score) AS max_score 
      FROM
         YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
      GROUP BY
         level
   )
   AS max_scores
```

Comment: This works great, thanks Sash, really appreciate your help. Now I'll try to group by user_id too :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct sum(max(score)) over () as "Total Score" from T group by level;
```

You can do the two aggregates together with `group by` and then a windowed sum. `Distinct` takes care of removing what would be the same sum repeated for every group. (In general I would encourage you to avoid too much reliance on `select distinct`.)

The other approaches using either CTEs/derived tables are perfectly fine. A beginner's solution would probably look more like this:

```
select t.level, sum(maxScore) as "Total Score"
from T t inner join
    (select level, max(score) as maxScore from T group by level) as m
        on m.level = t.level
group by t.level;
```

Depending on the platform you might get this to work

```
select level,
    sum((select max(score) from t t2 where t2.level = t.level)) as "Total Score"
from T t
group by level
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are searching for this solution. I hope it will fix your question.

```
WITH A as (
Select MAX(score) as "MAX order" FROM "YOUR TABLE" GROUP BY level)
SELECT SUM("MAX score per level") FROM a
```